# Mocha/Chai tests hanging at .should.be.deep.equal despite result existing

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mongoose, mocha.js, chai

I'm running some tests using Mocha and chai. One of the tests is hanging at a `.should.be.deep.equal` call.

Here's the test code:

```
// Make the fake connection before running tests
before(function(done) {
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://fake.test/TestingDB', function(err) {
        done(err);
    }); 
});

// Test Cases
describe('Testing the functions that deal with users and locations:', function() {
    // Test Setup
    var req = {};
    beforeEach(function(done) {
        mockgoose.reset()
        async.parallel([function(callback){
            sensors.create(testData.deviceData, function(err, model) {
                    if (err) {console.log(err)}
                    callback();
                });
        }, function(callback) {
            locations.create(testData.locationData, function(err, model) {
                    if (err) {console.log(err)}
                    callback();
                });
            }], function(err) {
                done();
            });
    });

    afterEach(function(done) {
        mockgoose.reset();
        done();
    });
    // Tests
    describe('function locationList', function() {
        it('should list the test location', function(done) {
            dbFunctions.locationList(req, function(result) {
                console.log(result) //Prints the whole result
                console.log(testData.locationList)
                result.should.exist; //This doesn't cause it to hang
                result.should.be.deep.equal(testData.locationList) //hangs here
                done(result);
            });
        })
    })
});
```

And here's the function it's testing:

```
exports.locationList = function(req, callback) {
listLocations().then(
    function(data) {
        callback(data);
    },
    function(err) {
        console.log('Error Retrieving Location Information: ' + err);
        callback(err);
    });
};
```

As I note in the comments, the results object exists and gets printed to the console. `results.should.exist;` doesn't throw an exception and if I comment out everything but it the test works fine. For some weird reason, despite both the `testData.locationList` and `result` object existing, the test times out. I have 14 other tests that use the exact same syntax without any problems. Does anyone know what could be causing this to happen for this specific test?

Here's the output from the tests:

```
Testing the functions that deal with users and locations:
    function locationList                            
        [ { devices: {},
            address: '123 Fake St, Waterloo, On',
            location: 'Unittest',
            owner: 'unit@test.com',
            _id: '-1' } ]         
        [ { devices: {},
            address: '123 Fake St, Waterloo, On',
            location: 'Unittest',
            owner: 'unit@test.com',
            _id: '-1' } ]          

            1) should list the test location
0 passing (2s)
1 failing
1) Testing the functions that deal with users and locations: function locationList should list the test location:
Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.
    at null.<anonymous> (C:\Users\My Name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runnable.js:189:19)
```

Extending the timeout doesn't work. Nor does putting something random (ie. the integer `1` in the `.should.be.deep.equal()` function.

Comment: I don't think this is a fix for your issue, but you probably should just call done() instead of done(result) as anything passed to done() will be interpreted as an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the callback in `exports.locationList` is called synchronously, and that your test case is actually failing, throwing an exception, which never gets caught because the callback is (synchronously) called from within a promise handler (more info [here](http://jamesknelson.com/are-es6-promises-swallowing-your-errors/)).

Try and see if this works better:

```
dbFunctions.locationList(req, function(result) {
  setImmediate(function() {
    console.log(result) //Prints the whole result
    console.log(testData.locationList)
    result.should.exist; //This doesn't cause it to hang
    result.should.be.deep.equal(testData.locationList) //hangs here
    done(result);
  });
});
// or use a module like dezalgo (https://github.com/npm/dezalgo)
```

The underlying cause may be `mockgoose`.

Also, you're not using the proper Node.js conventions where the first argument to a callback function is "reserved" for errors. In other words, your code should look similar to this:

```
if (err) {
  callback(err);
} else {
  callback(null, data);
}
```

You're now passing both errors *and* data as the first argument.

Comment: I'm marking your answer as accepted even though it isn't exactly what I did to fix this problem. Your suggestion did cause the silent error to appear, but for some weird (mockgoose related?) reason, it caused all my other tests to begin failing with `MongoError: topology was destroyed`. I then decided I'd rather not use promises, so edited my code to stop using them. This left all my tests still failing. From the diff, I saw that for some weird reason the whole mongo record was returned, not just the _doc. I rewrote the function to unpack those and push them into a list, and everything worked!

Comment: @ZacharyJacobi my experience is that mixing promises and callbacks is sometimes tricky, so it's best to commit to one solution (for your own code; third-party code that uses callbacks can usually be converted to promises by using something like bluebird's [`promisifyAll`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisifyall.html)). Mocha can handle promises natively, which is really nice.

Comment: the majority of the code in the module is using callbacks. I'm in the middle of merging two separate code bases, so I'll make a note to be sure to stick to one solution - probably callbacks.

Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1):

A guess: Maybe the issue lies with mongoose decorating the `result` with it's own functions/members, and one of them somehow getting stuck in an infinite loop when chai tries to enumerate them all to perform a deep comparison.